# Como puedo solucionar un error 415 cuando intento crear un usuario nuevo?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mongodb

Estoy construyendo tanto en Front-end como en Back-end las funcionalidades de Autenticación - BD Usuarios (CRUD) - Inventario de Productos (CRUD), Lo anterior se llevará a cabo en una BD NOSQL con MongoDB y se ajustarán los servicios web utilizando las dependencias adecuadas.

En lo que al Front-end se refiere, debo crear lo siguiente: Un formulario para que el Administrador pueda ingresar los datos de los Usuarios (Coordinadores de Zona y Asesores Comerciales) a la BD y una tabla de Administrador de Usuarios (CRUD). He hecho el backend y funciona correctamente, haciendo las pruebas con Postman, este me crea el usuario con POST y asi mismo consulta los usuarios con GET, sin embargo cuando intento crear un usuario desde el explorador al visualizar la consola no crea el usuario y me genera error POST /api/user/new 415, ademas de que no muestra los usuarios existentes en la tabla inferior. He estado leyendo y dicen que es un error en el JSON pero no creo que este sea mi caso.

Agradezco mucho la colaboracion de ustedes

```js
/**
 * Metodo que trae los registros existentes en la base de datos.
 */
function getUser () {
    $.ajax ({
        //url del servicio
        url: "http://localhost:8080/api/user/all",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (response) { 
            console.log(response);
            printListUser(response);
            
        }
        
    });
}

function printListUser (response) {
    let myTable = "<table>"
    
    for(i=0;response.lenght;i++){
        myTable += "<tr>";
        myTable += "<td>" + response[i].identification + "</td>";
        myTable += "<td>" + response[i].name + "</td>";
        myTable += "<td>" + response[i].address + "</td>";
        myTable += "<td>" + response[i].cellPhone + "</td>";
        myTable += "<td>" + response[i].email + "</td>";
        myTable += "<td>" + response[i].password + "</td>";
        myTable += "<td>" + response[i].zone + "</td>";
        myTable += "<td>" + response[i].type + "</td>";
        myTable+='<td><button class = "btn btn-primary btn-block fa-lg gradient-custom-2 mb-4" onclick="update(' + response[i].id + ')"> Update </button></td>';
        myTable+='<td><button class = "btn btn-primary btn-block fa-lg gradient-custom-2 mb-4" onclick="loadData(' + response[i].id + ')"> Edit </button></td>';
        myTable+='<td><button class = "btn btn-primary btn-block fa-lg gradient-custom-2 mb-4" onclick="deleted(' + response[i].id + ')"> Delete </button></td>';
        myTable+="</tr>";
        myTable+="</table>";
    }
    $("#myTableUser").html(myTable);
}
/** Metodo para guardar usuarios nuevos */

function registrar() {

    var datos = {
        id: $("#id").val,
        identification: $("#identificationUser").val,
        name: $("#txtName").val,
        address: $("#txtAddress").val,
        cellphone: $("#cellphone").val,
        email: $("#txtEmail").val,
        password: $("#password").val,
        zone: $("#zone").val,
        type: $("#type").val
    };

    console.log(datos)

    if ($('#identificationUser').val().length === 0 || $('#txtName').val().length === 0 || 
    $('#txtAddress').val().length === 0 || $('#cellphone').val().length === 0 || $('#txtEmail').val().length === 0 || 
    $('#password').val().length === 0 || $('#zone').val().length === 0 || $('#type').val().length === 0 ){
        alert('All fields are required');
        return;
    }

    /* Utilizo la funcion jquery $.ajax para para hacer un llamado asincrono */
    $.ajax ({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        headers: {
            "ContentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8" 
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(datos),

        //url del servicio
        url: "http://localhost:8080/api/user/new",
        
        statusCode: { 
            201: function (response) {
                $("#id").val("");
                $("#identificationUser").val("");
                $("#name").val("");
                $("#address").val("");
                $("#cellphone").val("");
                $("#email").val("");
                $("#password").val("");
                $("#zone").val("");
                $("#type").val("");

            console.log(response);
            console.log("Created User");
            alert("Successfull registration");
            window.location.reload()
        },
        400: function (response) {
            //window.location.reload()
            alert("It wasn't possible to create the account!");
        }
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: Prueba sin charset-utf8, solo aplication/json

Comment: Ya lo hice pero no funciono!